When TwoFactorEnabled is activated, I get an error during login (implementation with Identity)
I have an AccountController that contains all login, register, two-factor and other operations.
I set a status change in the user profile to enable and disable two-step login.
Everything is done correctly until the user activates it and when he tries to login again, he gets an error.
Error:
enter image description here

ArgumentException: Entity type 'IdentityUserToken' is defined with a 2-part composite key, but 3 values were passed to the 'Find' method.

It is better and clearer in the screenshot 
Class IdentityDataBaseContext:
    public class IdentityDataBaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public IdentityDataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser<string>>().ToTable("Users", "identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<string>>().ToTable("Roles", "identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims", "identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims", "identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins", "identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles", "identity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens", "identity");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().HasKey(p => new { p.LoginProvider, p.ProviderKey });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.LoginProvider });
    }
}

Thank you for helping me to solve this problem ❤

Did you configure IdentityUserToken in dbcontext?

As the error said, you could try following to config 3-part composite key.
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.LoginProvider,p.Name });


The problem is solved, thanks for your help

I added the last parameter which is p.Name and it worked.
